# FASTAPI: what is the difference in setting optional fields?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

i have 2 optional fields publish and ratings, here is my code

```
  class POST(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True
    rating: Optional[int] = None
```

They both result in optional field, so what is the difference between two?

if i try something like this, this also works

```
class POST(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True
    rating: int = None
```

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional

Comment: this explains pretty well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any difference except for the fact that by using Optional Key word we explicitly telling that this parameter Is optional both in code and swagger.

```
Note that this is not the same concept as an optional argument, which is one that has a default. An optional argument with a default does not require the Optional qualifier on its type annotation just because it is optional. For example:

def foo(arg: int = 0) -> None:
    ...
On the other hand, if an explicit value of None is allowed, the use of Optional is appropriate, whether the argument is optional or not. For example:

def foo(arg: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`rating: int = None` is not correct. It is a mistake but python simply ignores static typing so here is no difference in behaviour.

For example in Java you will get [`NullPointerException`](https://rollbar.com/blog/how-to-catch-and-fix-nullpointerexception-in-java/#:%7E:text=NullPointerException%20is%20a%20runtime%20exception,handled%20explicitly%20in%20application%20code.).

Try to use [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) for typing checks (`mypy post_model.py`)

`Optional` case will be completed without errors:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

However non `Optional` case will cause error:

```
post_model.py:7: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```